# How are names remembered with its associated memory address?

Tags: c++

In order to define my wonder, I think it would be great with an example:

- The variable x is declared with the initial value of 2 and has global scope

  ```
  int x = 2;
  ```
- Because that variable x has global scope, it is visible everywhere, which means that the compiler must somehow remember its memory address. Anyway, x is then changed from a given function called "bla"

  ```
  void bla()
  {
      x = 5;
  }
  ```
- So the compiler(not sure what handles all this) remembers this name "x" and can somehow know the memory address that belongs to the name x...

So my questions are:

1. How does the compiler(still not sure about this) remember what name/identifier and memory address that belong together? and where is this information stored - Is it also stored as memory addresses?
2. Technically, would it be faster if the programmer wrote the actual memory addresses instead of names so that the compiler(you probably know by now that I am not sure about what handles these things) does not have to replace all variables etc. with the addresses?

Thanks! I have really tried not to make anything ambiguous but if you still find it confusing, please comment or suggest an edit + please correct me if I am wrong, thanks again!

Comment: There's no mechanism defined by the C++ standard; each compiler is free to remember variables however it wants. Generally, they're going to use some kind of list of maps to track each nested scope and what each symbol means. It would not be much faster if the programmer wrote raw memory addresses. In fact, a human is going to be much slower at this kind of work than the compiler.

Comment: It can just stuff all the variables encountered into some sort of internal map.

Comment: First, understand that variable names do not exist in the output object file except for use by people for debugging. Next you need to understand what the linker does. Otherwise it seems simple and obvious to me. It would really help if you can explain the specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @user34660, I have tried to explain it... One of the things noted is the wondering about how the names are remembered to represent a certain memory address and where this data is stored. Whoops, just saw that you said "problem" - There is not any problem that I am trying to solve, it is just curiosity.

Comment: That is not a problem to be solved; it is a philosophical question that it is not the type of thing that StackOverflow is designed to help with. As @cdhowie says, it depends on the compiler writer's personal style.

Comment: See my [Flex](http://simplesamples.info/CPluPlus/Flex.aspx) and search for articles on Flex and Bison. Many articles about Bison and YACC will also describe symbol tables. That will entertain you for a while. Also search for articles such as [A Short Course in Compilers -- Symbol Tables and Type](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mckeeman/cs48/mxcom/doc/Symbols.html) and [Compiler Design - Symbol Table](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_symbol_table.htm). There are many **books** about compiler construction; you might find one in a library.

Comment: Thanks but I still do not understand where and how the names/identifiers are saved and remembered so that the compiler remembers what memory address they refer to. And does this data also have an address that the compiler will access in order to check what names refer to what memory address?

Comment: The names don't have a memory address associated with them until the linker gets through with the code. So the compiler just stores them in a symbol table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more in-depth understanding, you have to consult some learning resources about language- and compilerdesign.

The definition of the C++ language comes with a concept of declaration points and scopes. These things need to be respected by compilers, so for every expression in a well formed code, the compiler will know which scope this expression belongs to and how the scopes are nested.

A typical compiler implementation will have a data structure, where each scope is associated with a symbol table, where the declared / defined symbols of the current scope are listed. Now, when the compiler (typical implementation, it can possibly be done completely different!) encounters a symbol in code (like the `x = 5;`), it will look into the symbol table of the current scope and its parent scope, until the symbol `x` is first found. Then the symbol usage is linked with the symbol definition as it was found in one of the symbol tables.

Skipping some details, your example contains at least the following scope nesting:

```
global scope
  function bla scope
    function bla body scope
```

Since `x` is not locally declared / defined in any of the inner scopes, the compiler will link the usage to the definition which is found in global scope.

> Technically, would it be faster if the programmer wrote the actual
>   memory addresses instead of names so that the compiler(you probably
>   know by now that I am not sure about what handles these things) does
>   not have to replace all variables etc. with the addresses?

When we talk about development, the compiler will be much faster than the programmer at this task, so no time saving here.

Regarding program execution, the symbol doesn't exist anymore (except for debugging information) because the compiler is replacing it by its program-local memory address. Generally you can't save execution time by doing any thing by hand which is otherwise done by the compiler.